# Printing from logical expressions in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala I have an expression like:

```
 prods <- Products.getAll(pr => (pr.stockOn >= from &&
                                 !(outOfDate(pr.id))
                                )
                         )
```

Is it possible to have a println command in the expression:

```
(pr.stockOn >= from && !(outOfDate(pr.id)) )
```

Something like:

```
 (pr.stockOn >= from && !(outOfDate(pr.id)) && (println(outOfDate(pr.id)))
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple lines of code in the body of the function. I would write it like this:

```
prods <- Products.getAll{pr =>
  val ood = outOfDate(pr.id)

  println(ood)

  pr.stockOn >= from && !ood
}
```

The last value in the block is the result of the block.

Comment: but you are using {}  instead of ()

Comment: Yes, that is OK. A function that takes a single argument can take a block in `{}` instead of an expression in `()`.

Answer (score 3):

Some people like

```
pr.stockOn >= from && !outOfDate(pr.id) && { println(outOfDate(pr.id)) ; true }
```

In 2.13, there is

```
import scala.util.chaining._

outOfDate(pr.id).tap(println).pipe(!_)
```

which has the benefit of being weirdly cryptic.